# JCheckBox in Table Model

Tags: java, jtable, jcheckbox

I have this table model and I want to get Checkboxes in the first column.
How can I do this? Do I have to make an extra column in my table?

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();


        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
        }

        rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> newRow = new Vector<Object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                }

            rows.addElement(newRow);
            }

        return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
```

I already tried this. It is working, but I don't want to make an extra column in my table and I also want to have a Checkbox on the top which selects all other ons. Does anyone knows how it works?

```
table.getColumn("Select").setCellRenderer(
                  table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a JCheckBox to DefaultTableModel by adding a Boolean column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690488/how-do-i-add-a-jcheckbox-to-defaulttablemodel-by-adding-a-boolean-column)

Comment: No, i want to add checkbox without adding an extra column in my table. I am getting the data from a mySQL table.

Comment: Read it again carefully. The question and answer explain how to "automatically returns a checkbox for you if you render a Boolean.class in a column"

Comment: See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingdefaultBooleanvaluecelleditorandrenderer.htm for a simple example